# Algebra Problem: Two airplanes flying in opposite directions.

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried to create the equation and failed. Maybe somebody could help me?

Two airplanes start flying from an airport in opposite directions, one averaging a speed of 40 km/hr greater than that of the other. If they are 5600 km apart after 5 hours, find their average speed in kilometer per hour.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let speed of be $x$ then other's will be $x+40$.

$\leftarrow---x \frac{km}{h}..(x+1)\frac{km}{h}----\rightarrow$

If one is moving left with $x$ and other is moving to right with $x+10$ then both are moving with $2x+10$ away from each other.

$s_r=\dfrac{d_r}{t}$; $40+2x=\dfrac{5600}{5}$, solve the equation to get speed.

Where $s_r$ and $d_r$ are their relative velocities and displacements respectively. If two objects are moving opposite to each other their relative velocity is sum of their individual velocities.

So, their velocities are $540$ and $580$ respectively.

Comment: Solved my problem... :).

Comment: glad to help you!

Comment: But, could you be a bit more specific and explain?

Comment: it edited the solution

Comment: Still didn't catch it... Just in class VII

Comment: okay i am again editing it to make it easier to understand

Comment: Got it...:)....